# ORA-29263 thrown error ONLY when URL becomes LONG

Tags: oracle, http, oracle11g, request

I am trying to call a restful service from my ora pkg; Sometimes with the same code, this service is reached successfully and a response is returned; but when the message in the url becomes longer ==> ORA-29273 http request and ORA-29263 http protocol are thrown; I do not change anything between calls, only messages to be sent from this URL; Below is my procedure:

```
PROCEDURE SEND_SMS(username   VARCHAR2,
                   password   VARCHAR2,
                   phone      VARCHAR2,
                   message    VARCHAR2,
                   code       VARCHAR2,                 
                   P_RESPONSE OUT VARCHAR2) AS

    v_request         UTL_HTTP.req;
    v_response        UTL_HTTP.resp;
    v_text            VARCHAR2(1024);
    v_url             VARCHAR2(1024);
    v_message         VARCHAR2(1024);


  BEGIN
    BEGIN

      P_RESPONSE := '';
      v_message  := REPLACE(message,' ', '%20');


      v_url             := 'http://myservicelink.com/SendSMS?strUsername=' |
                           username || '&strPassword=' || password ||
                           '&strPhone=' || phone || '&strcode=' || code ||
                           '&strMessage=' || v_message;
      v_request         := UTL_HTTP.begin_request(v_url);

      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(v_url);

      v_response := UTL_HTTP.get_response(v_request);

      LOOP
        BEGIN
          UTL_HTTP.read_text(v_response, v_text);
          DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(v_text);
        EXCEPTION
          WHEN UTL_HTTP.end_of_body THEN
            NULL;
        END;

        EXIT WHEN v_text IS NULL;
      END LOOP;

      UTL_HTTP.end_response(v_response);

      IF v_response.status_code <> 200 THEN
        P_RESPONSE := v_response.reason_phrase;
      END IF;

    EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
       P_RESPONSE := 'An error has occured: ' || SQLERRM;
    END;

  END SEND_SMS;
```

So when v_message becomes longer, exception is thrown. What can be the error; Please note that the same link is called from outside ORA pkg with same inputs --> myservice is reached;

Here is a template of my working message:
`Dear X, you have been registered to our app. You can download the app for iPhone at link of app store or for android at link of`

Not working:
`Dear X, you have been registered to our app. You can download the app for iPhone at link of app store or for android at link of play store
your`

Comment: Good to see you are keeping up a fine IT tradition with `'An error has occured'` :)

Comment: Is it the length of the message, or that you've added a newline? (Also, why are you manually replacing spaces - and only spaces - rather than using say [utl_url.escape](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/arpls/UTL_URL.html#GUID-1AD609BE-A0DE-41C3-8F86-4C11BCEA658B)?)

Comment: Ohhhh @AlexPoole you saved my day! I didn't know about the escape, when I replaced it, the webservice was called successfully, Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between your two strings isn't just length; the second one has a newline character in it as well. You are replacing spaces using:

```
v_message  := REPLACE(message,' ', '%20');
```

but that won't deal with any other illegal characters.

If you change that to use [the `utl_url.escape()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/arpls/UTL_URL.html#GUID-1AD609BE-A0DE-41C3-8F86-4C11BCEA658B):

```
v_message  := utl_url.escape(message);
```

then it will escape the new line as well, so you end up with this for the first message (same as your current code gives):

> `Dear%20X,%20you%20have%20been%20registered%20to%20our%20app.%20You%20can%20download%20the%20app%20for%20iPhone%20at%20link%20of%20app%20store%20or%20for%20android%20at%20link%20of`

but this for the second:

> `Dear%20X,%20you%20have%20been%20registered%20to%20our%20app.%20You%20can%20download%20the%20app%20for%20iPhone%20at%20link%20of%20app%20store%20or%20for%20android%20at%20link%20of%20play%20store%0Ayour`

The newline has been encoded as `%0A`. Depending on what else is in the message, you may need to pass `true` as the second argument instead of letting it default to `false`; the difference is explained in the documentation link above.

Comment: Yes now I understand; That's why sometimes it succeeds and sometimes it doesn't